# Python pass variable to another python file with out making changes in one file. More or less like a sed equivalent in Unix

Tags: python, unix

Script 1: I have a Python file that out puts a variable - date
Script 2 : I have a second python file and i would like to pass the variable from first script to second script.

I donot want to make any change to script 2. All that would help me is to replace the variable in script 2 with the variable from script 1

I want the value computed for x in script 1 to become the value for x in script 2 without making changes to script 2?

Script 1 :
some code
return x;
print(x)

script 2:
x = 2.

I would like to add some code in script 1 that changes the variable value with the output from script 1.
Just like what a sed command does in unix

Thanks

Comment: Since your question has been marked as a duplicate (and not that I agree), I would say submit another question containing sample code for script 1, and greater clarity. Do you want to value computed for `x` in script 1 to become the value for `x` in script 2 without making changes to script 2?

Comment: That exactly my requirement. Could you please help me out with that

Comment: Not here because this question has been marked as a duplicate. That's why I suggested submitting another question.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to wrap whatever you are doing in script 1 in a function, then return from that function. In script 2, call `x = script1.function()`.

Comment: The Problem is i cant make any changes in script 2

Answer (score 0):

**script1.py**

```
x=2
```

**script2.py**

```
from script1 import x as x_value

x = x_value
print (x)
```

Result of running script2:

```
2
```

Comment: Hi Bill, But the problem is i cant make any changes to script 2.